# Como seleciono dados importados no R?

Tags: r

Preciso analisar meus dados com PCA no **R** ***(versão 3.3.2)***, e o tutorial que tenho de uma versão mais antiga parece não se aplicar.
Importei os dados em `.xlsx` e segundo o que eu sei, preciso selecionar os dados numéricos para análise em PCA usando o pacote `stats`, tirando as linhas e colunas que nomeiam as variáveis.
Os comandos que eu tinha para testar são: `dadosnumericos <- dados[,3:25]`, como exemplo, e aparecem várias mensagens de erro.

Comment: Seja bem-vinda ao Stack Overflow em Português. Visto que você tentou fazer alguma coisa, consegue estruturar melhor a pergunta, enfatizando suas tentativas, junto com as mensagens de erro? Assim facilitará quem for te ajudar.

Comment: Oi Paola, você tem certeza que conseguiu carregar os dados corretamente? Se puder, edite a sua pergunta adicionando o resultado de quando você roda `str(dados)` no  console do R. Assim vai ficar mais fácil entender o que pode estar dando errado p/ você. Também vai ficar mais fácil se você adicionar na sua pergunta uma cópia das mensagens de erro que apareceram para você. Obrigado!